# Does ElasticSearch support define fixed ranking strategy?

Tags: ranking, elasticsearch

Everytime I use the same query, such as code below:

```
{
"bool": {
    "should": [
        {
          "multi_match" : {
            "query":      "Will Smith",
            "type":       "cross_fields",
            "fields":     [ "first", "last" ],
            "minimum_should_match": "50%" 
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match" : {
            "query":      "Will Smith",
            "type":       "cross_fields",
            "fields":     [ "*.edge" ]
          }
        }
    ]
}}
```

Each time I use different query word, but the params are the same.

Does elasticsearch support this kind of strategy we can define, like ranking strategy? Each time I just need to input the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch supports [template](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html#_more_template_examples) query where you can register a query and pass the query string as a param

Example:

1. Create a ***.scripts*** index if it doesn't exists

> ```
> PUT <server::port>/.scripts
> ```

2. Register the query template for the above case

> ```
>  PUT <server::port>/_search/template/<template_name>
>  {    
>   "template": {
>   "query": {
>      "bool": {
>         "should": [
>            {
>               "multi_match": {
>                  "query": "{{query_string}}",
>                  "type": "cross_fields",
>                  "fields": [
>                     "first",
>                     "last"
>                  ],
>                  "minimum_should_match": "50%"
>               }
>            },
>            {
>               "multi_match": {
>                  "query": "{query_string}",
>                  "type": "cross_fields",
>                  "fields": [
>                     "*.edge"
>                  ]
>               }
>            }
>         ]
>      }
>   }
> ```
>
> } 
>   }

3. Invoke search template with *query_string* param

> ```
>  POST <server::port>/index>/_search/template {    
>     "template": {
>         "id": "<template_name>"    
>     },    
>     "params": {
>         "query_string": "will smith"    
>     }      
>  }
> ```

Comment: This is little different from this: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-template-query.html#_stored_templates . I tried the official examples, but cannot get result for my query. Do you have any idea about how to use url: /_search instead of /_search/template ?

Comment: if u intend to use the _search endpoint , you would need to change the template query  to the following https://gist.github.com/keety/610613edbbbd8dce8e6b